# Access pointers stored in multimap -C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am maintaining a multimap to store pointer variables, code compiles fine but throws exception. please review my code below and provide suggestion

```
multimap<const char*, int **> myMap1;
    int *myVals = new int[3];

    myVals[0] = 1;
    myVals[1] = 1;
    myVals[2] = 1;

    myMap1.insert(pair<const char*, int **>("val1", &myVals));

    std::multimap<const char*, int **>::iterator it = myMap1.find("val1");
    int *storedVals =  reinterpret_cast<int *>(it->second);

    for(int ii = 0; ii< 2; ii++)
    {
        printf("\n Value %d", storedVals[ii]); //Exception thrown here..
    }

    delete myVals;
```

Comment: For starters, `myVals` needs to be `new int[3]`, or you need to remove the assignment to `myVals[2]`. You should also use `delete[] myVals` since `myVals` is an array.

Comment: Suggestion: Extract a minimal but complete example and quote the output, as per posting guidelines for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unless you're code is optimized for identical-const-string consolidation, I don't see how this can work. The operator used for comparing keys, when those keys are `const char *` likely isn't doing what you think it is. You're trying to find two matching `const char *`, i.e. the pointer values matching, not what they point to as content-comparison. And you never check whether the find succeeded and blindly hit up the iterator.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes those check should be added, I have them in my actual code.It is code snippet in which exception could be reproduced.

Comment: Along the line I mentioned, if you included the `<string>` standard header and changed your map to be `<std::string,int**>` its likelihood of not faulting will go up considerably. Think carefully about what is being mapped now vs. with that change, and how key value comparisons differ between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your code as below, and refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689981/multimap-on-c-style-string-key-fails-to-insert-entries) link if you wanna know why.

```
multimap<const char*, int **> myMap1;
int *myVals = new int[3];

myVals[0] = 1;
myVals[1] = 1;
myVals[2] = 1;
char * temp = "val1";
myMap1.insert(pair<const char*, int **>(temp, &myVals));

std::multimap<const char*, int **>::iterator it = myMap1.find(temp);
int *storedVals =  *(it->second);

for(int ii = 0; ii<= 2; ii++)
{
    printf("\n Value %d", storedVals[ii]); //Exception thrown here..
}

delete [] myVals;
```

Also prefer to use `auto it` for iterators instead of `std::multimap<const char*, int **>::iterator it`. Also you cant use 'reinterpret_cast' here.

Comment: The `myMap.find("val1")` always returned `myMap.end()` so you were getting runtime exception. Your program should have worked if you had used `myMap.begin()` instead of `myMap.find("val1")` for iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the reason why you are using a `reinterpret_cast` here:

Your value (`second`) in the map is holding a pointer to a `int*`

If you change this line with the following. It would work:

```
int *storedVals =  *(it->second); //it->second is a int**
```

Also you should not do `myVals[2] = 1;` your array size is 2. Alternatively you can increase the size of your array to 3.

Comment: it did not solved. I got a exception while                                      int *storedVals =  *(it->second);

Comment: I am still getting exception on change added, I am running it from VS 2010 as a console application.